# How do you Trigger a Technical Profile if Validation Technical Profile fails

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am wanting to log the error if the validation technical profile fails. Since the app insight log is in a technical profile... how do I trigger it?

The code below is in the technical profile that the orchestration step points to.
The send Data step seems to fail a decent amount of time, and I want to log it.
Is there a way to keep the "ContinueOnError="False" but also run a technical profile ONLY if it errors?

```
<ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="REST-AcquireAccessToken" />
            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="REST-SendData" ContinueOnError="false">
              <Preconditions>
                <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
                <Value>extension_1</Value>
                <Value>extension_2</Value>
                <Action>SkipThisValidationTechnicalProfile</Action>
              </Precondition>
              </Preconditions>
            </ValidationTechnicalProfile>
          </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
```

Answer (score 0):

In situations where error capture needs to be more granular that what is available, I've seen many people create an extensionAttribute within the policy and pipe the error code into the claim bag. The App insights will capture the data being piped into that specific claim type and you can create logging analytics to track when this claim is populated with XYZ error code value.

Using default values to these extensionAttributes can be powerful. You can make assumptions and logic something like extensionAttribute error = true unless the validation technical profile is updates it to 'false' with a claimtransformation. Azure App Insights should be able to track this data as well if enabled.

Alternatively, you can use the method above to trigger a REST-SendDataFAILED validation technical profile that is triggered in the scenario where it fails (this would allow you to capture the data regardless of if it is triggered but again, this should be triggered on preconditions and leveraging attributes. Make sure you output any claims in your validation technical profile to ensure that value is in the claim bag for the next precondition.

Comment: So I thought of the validation technical profile, but from my understanding, if you have continueOnError=false, the validation step stops there..

Comment: I can't recall - this needs to be tested but my comment still is true. Push the 'contineOnError=fase' to the next validaton technical profile but make sure you LOG this on this technical profile. That way, it still STOPS when it too but you still capture the data. Does this make sense?

Comment: I think so... basically keep what i have, add another validation technical profile, however, I need to add a claimexists precondition to it to see if there is an error and if there is, then run the technical profile... The only part im not sure of is how to get an output claim from the previous step ONLY if it fails...

Comment: This requirement is null if you are OK with a default value that controls the business logic. If whatever reason this is a must, I suggest creating an output claim transformation that generates a value based on the response of the call. So, with this logic the claim will not be populated when the validation technical 'fails'. But again, you don't have to only the 'ClaimExist' precondition, there's also 'ClaimEquals'. I think your question is hyper focused on the implementation than the business use case. There is not a single solution to your problem.